# ListView not follow order to display after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I dont know why my output of listview always in wrong order after I update the data in my activity.

This is how I initialize the adapter in my activity

```
inboxTradeAdapter=new InboxTradeAdapter(InboxTradeActivity.this, R.layout.activity_inbox_trade, tradeArrayList,loginUserId);
tradeList.setAdapter(inboxTradeAdapter);
```

I call

```
inboxTradeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after tradeArrayList is updated

This is my Adapter

```
public class InboxTradeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Trade> {
private List<Trade> tradeList;
private Context context;
private String loginUserId;

public InboxTradeAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Trade> tradeList, String loginUserId) {
    super(context, resource, tradeList);
    this.context = context;
    this.tradeList = tradeList;
    this.loginUserId=loginUserId;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != tradeList) ?
            tradeList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public Trade getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != tradeList) ?
            tradeList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (null == view) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_category, null);
    }

    final Trade trade = tradeList.get(position);

    if (trade != null) {
        final CardView tradeLayout = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_gridlayout);
        final TextView tradeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        final ImageView tradeImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);

        tradeName.setText(trade.getNameOwn());
        tradeName.setSelected(true);

        tradeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, category.getId()+" "+category.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, InboxActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("loginUserId", loginUserId);
                intent.putExtra("tradeId",String.valueOf(trade.getId()));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

I can confirm that the tradeArrayList order is correct in my activity but the listview display the trade in random order. I cannot find the bug, please help

Comment: What is out of order? Just the name or both, name and icon?

Comment: @W0rmH0le display the listview in random order. For example,first time display 1,2,3. Then I run again,it will display 2,3,1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, create a view holder in adapter and create a setter to set the tradeList before call the notifyDataSetChanged()

This is my answer

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final Trade trade = tradeList.get(position);
    Log.d("worked",position+": "+trade.getId());

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_trade, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tradeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trade_name);
        holder.tradeLayout = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trade_listlayout);
        holder.tradeImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trade_icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (trade != null) {

        holder.tradeName.setText(trade.getNameOwn());
        holder.tradeName.setSelected(true);

        try {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(trade.getImageOwnOne())
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .into(holder.tradeImage);
        }catch(Exception e){
            holder.tradeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        }
        holder.tradeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, category.getId()+" "+category.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DisplayTradeActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("trade", trade);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.tradeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, category.getId()+" "+category.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, InboxActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("loginUserId", loginUserId);
                intent.putExtra("tradeId",String.valueOf(trade.getId()));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    return convertView;
}

public void setTradeList(ArrayList<Trade> tl) {
    this.tradeList = tl;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tradeName;
    private CardView tradeLayout;
    private ImageView tradeImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your not using a holder pattern. Always utilize it for optimization. 
To the issue at hand, try refactoring your code using the holder pattern. You can learn more about it online.

There is no need overriding the `getItem()` method too.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  final ViewHolder holder;
  Trade trade = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_category, parent, false);
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.tradeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
         holder.tradeLayout = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_gridlayout);
         holder.tradeImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }  

    holder.tradeName.setText(trade.getNameOwn());
    holder.tradeName.setSelected(true);

    holder.tradeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, category.getId()+" "+category.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, InboxActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("loginUserId", loginUserId);
          intent.putExtra("tradeId",String.valueOf(trade.getId()));
          context.startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
     }                        

    return convertView;
   }
 }
```

Your viewholder class code:

```
static class ViewHolder {
       private TextView tradeName;
       private TextView tradeLayout;
       private ImageView tradeImage;
  }
```

Comment: How to initialize mInflater?

Comment: even I use ViewHolder design, listview display in randam order also